# nginx add_header not applied to some server contexts

Tags: http, nginx

I have several `add_header` directives in my main `http` context of the `nginx.conf` file, such as:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
```

There no other such directives in `server` and `location` contexts. For some reason, the header is not applied to `server` contexts. For example, this one:

```
server {
        server_name my.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1:12345;
        }

        location /robots.txt {
            return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n";
        }

        client_max_body_size 300M;
    
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    }
```

What could be causing this?

EDIT: nginx version is 1.23.3.

The file `options-ssl-nginx.conf` in `/etc/letsencrypt/` has:

```
ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 1440m;
ssl_session_tickets off;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
# + one line of ssl_ciphers
```

Comment: Do the headers are never applied ? Looks like since `1.7.5` you have to ad the `always` parameter to set the header also on response error: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header
Did you restart the nginx main process since you've applied these changes ? I'm not sure that defining "global" headers like this are taken into account with a simple reload. BTW, what's your version of nginx ?

Comment: What's in `options-ssl-nginx.conf`?

Comment: Added requested detail to the question. Adding `always` seems to have fixed this. Thanks!

Comment: Good, added the fix has a real answer if you could validate it, thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in comment, adding the `always` parameter to the `add_header` directive allows the header to be added for all kind of HTTP responses (errors included), see the doc for more details: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header